# Unknown C++ error: Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle

Tags: c++, data-structures, error-handling

I have been searching all over the internet to try and understand why I am getting this error, but I have only ever seen this appear in other programming languages I am unfamiliar with or with code I have never used before.

I am working on a quicksort program for a school assignment, and everything was going well until I decided to consolidate the median bubble sort algorithm into a helper function.

```cpp
int* QS::MedianSort(int left, int middle, int right) {
    cout << "starting MedianSort...\n";////////////
    int temp;
    static int sort [] = { left, middle, right };
    do {
            if (sort[0] <= sort[1] && sort[1] <= sort[2]) {
                break;
            }
            else if (sort[1] < sort[0]) {
                temp = sort[1];
                sort[1] = sort[0];
                sort[0] = temp;
            }
            else if (sort[2] < sort[1]) {
                temp = sort[2];
                sort[2] = sort[1];
                sort[1] = temp;
            }

    } while(true);

    cout << "...returning sort from Median Sort\n";//////////
    return sort;
}
```

An example of its implementation in my partitioning algorithm:

```cpp
        int *temp;
        int tempInt;

        temp = MedianSort(*(array + left), *(array + pivotIndex), *(array + right));
        *(array + left) = *(temp + 0);
        *(array + pivotIndex) = *(temp + 1);
        *(array + right) = *(temp + 2);

        tempInt = *(array + pivotIndex); 
        *(array + pivotIndex) = *(array + left);
        *(array + left) = tempInt;
```

`array` is a pointer to an array that I am quicksorting, `left` is the smallest index being passed into the partition function, and `right` is the largest.

When I compile the code, it goes without a problem, but as soon as I run the executable, I get this error in the console:

```sh
Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle
Aborted
```

I don't understand why, because it finishes with the 3rd input file out of 5, but doesn't even start the 4th file. (I know this because I have `cout` statements at the beginning almost every function to show me how far it is getting.)

Also, `main.cpp` has been successfully going through all the files up to this point.

EDIT:
I am compiling with `-g -std=c++11`

Comment: P.S. I have been working on this for hours, so I am getting some shuteye. Will be active again to clarify anything in about 7 hours.

Comment: I do not see any file in your code.

Comment: @ZDF the files are called in main.cpp, this is in a header definition file. The file’s info only contains arguments and function calls.

Comment: Your problem is file related: you should show your `main`, ideally providing a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, `main.cpp` has been successfully going through all the files up to this point.

Are you sure? This problem is usually file-related. You should provide it or the scope involved in the file processing to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong with this line:

```
static int sort [] = .....
```

as if i understand correctly, static varible will only be initialized once (first time the function being called).

Comment: Altough correct, this should not cause the reported error

Comment: Note that this should probably be a comment instead. Once you get 50 reputation, you will be able to do that instead.

Comment: Will do so. Thank you.